# Gorm read only field after create

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to make one of the property of model as read only after create.
My code in working but when I try to update It will not throw any error.

Could you please help me in how to get error when we try to Update?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    ProductID int    `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Code      string `gorm:"->;<-:create"`
    Price     uint
}

// TestSuite is code to all tests, independent of database
func TestSuite(db *gorm.DB) { // Migrate the schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
    // Create
    db.Create(&Product{Code: "D4222", Price: 1000, ProductID: 3})
    // Read
    var product Product
    db.First(&product, "product_id = ?", 3) // find product with product_id 2
    fmt.Println("Product Code After Creation: ", product.Code)
    fmt.Println("Product Price After Creation: ", product.Price)

    //Update
    err := db.Model(&product).Where("product_id = ?", 3).Updates(Product{Price: 400, Code: "F42"}).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Read after update
    var updateProd Product
    db.First(&updateProd, "product_id = ?", 3) // find product with product_id 2
    fmt.Println("Product Code After Update: ", updateProd.Code)
    fmt.Println("Product Price After Update: ", updateProd.Price)

    // Delete - delete product
    db.Unscoped().Delete(&updateProd, 3)
}
```

```
Output:
Product Code After Creation: D4222
Product Price After Creation: 1000
Product Code After Update: D4222
Product Price After Update: 400
```

Answer (score 1):

if your table not created you don't have any problem

if your table created and you wanna to make two of the property of model as read only following below:

```
type Test struct {
       EnvID     string      `json:"env_id" gorm:"->"`                                                                                       
       PartID    string      `json:"part_id" gorm:"index:depl_part;unique;priority:3;->"`
}
```

then you must be to run following code

```
err := Client.AutoMigrate(&Test{})
```

now EnvID and PartID are READ-ONLY until you delete -> from GORM and run top code.

Comment: I am already using Automigrate but it is not working. BTW I am using postgres.

Comment: Can i see your code?

Comment: Check the description Please. This one is my POC.